# Sort vector with character and number in R

Tags: r

I want to sort vectors like

m=c(1,"<4",5,7,"<12",15,18,"<21","<25",27)
n=c(2,"<4",8,17,20,25,34,"<35",40,43)

to be ordered by only numbers

Output like (1,2,"<4","<4",5,7,8,...,<35,40,43)

I tried mixedsort in gtools library, but it doesn't work.

And, is there any function i mark which vector the every element comes from?

for example, 0 for numbers from vector m and 1 for vector n

and get output like (0,1,0,1,0,0,1,...,1,1,1)

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We set the `names` of 'm' and 'n' with '0' and '1', concatenate it to a single `vector`, and `order` by extracting the numeric part in the new vector (using `gsub`) convert to `numeric`, `order` it and use that index to order the 'n1'.

```
n1 <- c(setNames(m, rep(0, length(m))),setNames(n, rep(1, length(n))))
r1 <- n1[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", n1)))]

as.vector(r1)
#[1] "1"   "2"   "<4"  "<4"  "5"   "7"   "8"   "<12" "15"  "17"  "18"  "20"  
#[13]  "<21" "<25" "25"  "27"  "34"  "<35" "40"  "43" 

as.integer(names(r1))
#[1] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
```